# Triple covers of $\mathbb{P}^2$ with Tschirnhausen module $\mathcal{O}(-1)\oplus\mathcal{O}(-1)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

Let $X$ be a surface as in the title. [Rick Miranda](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2374349?origin=crossref) said that $X$ is a Steiner cubic in $\mathbb{P}^4$, and the cover map is projection. Invariants of $X$ can be computed directly, $p_g(X)=0,K^2_X=8,e(X)=4$.

My question is,

> **Question:** What is a Steiner cubic? Why $X$ is a Steiner cubic?

The followings are what I know:
Given $a,b,c,d\in H^0(\mathbb{P}^2,\mathcal{O}(1))$, $X$ is locally defined by
\begin{cases}
F(z,w)=z^2-aw-bw-2(a^2-bd) \\
G(z,w)=zw+dz+aw+ad-bc\\
H(z,w)=w^2-cz-dw-2(d^2-ac)
\end{cases}
Does, in fact, $X$ globally defined as an intersection of three quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^4$?

Comment: A locally  complete intersection of three quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^4$ is a curve, not a surface.

Comment: Maybe I should not say it is a locally complete intersection. I mean that $X$ is just like a two-dimensional version of a twisted cubic curve in $\mathbb{P}^3$ which is an intersection of three quadrics.

Comment: So there are no triple covers in the question?

Comment: Usually, Steiner surface is defined as the image of a regular liner projection of the Veronese surface into $\mathbb{P}^3$, see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinerSurface.html

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer, see "[Triple planes with p_g=q=0](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.02102.pdf)" Proposition 3.1 $X$ is a cubic scroll $S(1,2)\subset\mathbb{P}^4$, the image of Hirzebruch surface $\mathbb{F}_1$ under the linear system $|c_0+2f|$, where $c_0$ is the section with $c_0^2=-1$ and $f$ is the class of fiber.